# About the Index in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, index, btree

I have a question about indexes in `MYSQL`.

- I have a table, `DIM_BANK`.
- The primary key is the column `ID_BANK`. MySQL automatically created the an index for this with the following attributes - `BTREE (CLUSTERED), UNIQUE`.
- I create a regular index on the `varchar` column `DESC_BANK`, with the following attributes - `BTREE NOT UNIQUE`.
- When i execute my query, the results are shown in order by `DESC_BANK`.

My question is why are they shown in order by `DESC_BANK`?  As I understand clustered indexes, they enforce the ordering of the rows of the table physically.

I'm using the InnoDB engine in MySQL 8.0.

Comment: Can you please share your select query?

Answer (score 1):

> they enforce the ordering of the rows of the table physically

In fact most RDBMS do not order the results by default until `ORDER BY` is declared explicitly. Some ordered results can occure occasionally because of coincidence, say if you SELECT the data previously INSERTed in some order. But that behaviour isn't reliable and you can't count on it without `ORDER BY` clause. You should suggest any result without `ORDER BY` as randomly shuffled to avoid unforseen consequencies.